# Как реализовать move семантику в методе класса

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть класс, содержащий контейнер объектов (кораблей). Хочу через метода класса изменять свойство одного объекта. Метод сам возвращает bool (признак того, что объект найден или нет), а сам объект (внимание) хочу возвращать через параметр метода.

Проблема - мой объект **FindShip** удаляется при выходе из метода. Как сделать так, чтобы он продолжал жить?

```
void SeaGame::PlayerShoot(const Point& In)
{
Ship FindShip; //создаю временный объект, который нужно изменить

if (!ComputerField->FindShipByPoint(In,FindShip))
    return;
//что-то делаем с объектом
FindShip.setDeckByPoint(In, true);              
}

//метод
//Result - должен возвращать искомый объект
bool FindShipByPoint(const Point& p, Ship& Result) const
{
    for (Ship ship: _ships) //_ships - котейнер stl
    {
        for (Point _p : ship.getPoints())

            if (p == _p) //реализован соответствующий operator
            {
               Result = ship; //реализовано operator= (копирующее присваивание) 
               return true;
            }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Нужно ли тут делать rvalue-ссылки? Или они тут не причем?

Comment: У вас просто локальный объект, уничтожаемый при выходе. Для чего-то он вам нужен? верните его из метода `PlayerShoot` и сохраните. Семантика перемещения здесь в полной мере ни при чем. Просто по окончании области видимости объект уничтожается...

Comment: Да, его еще можно сделать статическим - будет висеть в вашей функции, но это точно то, что вам нужно? *Что вы хотите с ним делать после завершения `PlayerShoot`*?

Comment: PlayerShoot - это действие игрока, оно ничего не возвращает (void). В нем метод FindShipByPoint, я хочу чтобы он делал два действия сразу - возвращал bool, и найденный объект через 2-й аргумент (Result). Но он уничтожается. Поставлю вопрос так - можно ли как-нибудь его возвращать (и не уничтожать при return)

Comment: Дополню - именно через аргумент.
Хотя Ваша реализация ниже мне нравится!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы менять объект контейнера, нужно возвращать указатель/ссылку на него. Ссылки не могут быть нулевыми, поэтому вернуть не получится, а ссылка на ссылку в аргументе тем более запрещена. Поэтому остаётся только возвращать указатель на требуемый объект (как и делают в таких ситуациях).

---

Замечу, что добавил амперсанд в цикле по кораблям и точкам, чтобы не происходило копирования при каждой итерации и можно было вернуть указатель на реальный объект, а не локальную копию.

```
void SeaGame::PlayerShoot(const Point& In)
{
    Ship* FindShip = ComputerField->FindShipByPoint(In);

    if (!FindShip)
        return;
    //что-то делаем с объектом
    FindShip->setDeckByPoint(In, true);              
}

Ship* FindShipByPoint(const Point& p) const
{
    for (Ship &ship: _ships) // захват по ссылке
    {
        for (Point &_p : ship.getPoints()) // аналогично - чтобы не копировать зря

            if (p == _p)
            {
               return &ship; // не нужно ничего копировать, только вернем указатель
            }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

---

Если очень хочется через аргумент:

```
void SeaGame::PlayerShoot(const Point& In)
{
    Ship* FindShip;
    if (!ComputerField->FindShipByPoint(In, FindShip))
        return;

    //что-то делаем с объектом
    FindShip->setDeckByPoint(In, true);              
}

bool FindShipByPoint(const Point& p, Ship* &result) const
{
    for (Ship &ship: _ships) // захват по ссылке
    {
        for (Point &_p : ship.getPoints()) // аналогично - чтобы не копировать зря

            if (p == _p)
            {
               result = &ship;
               return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

С использованием STL всё проще:

```
Ship* FindShipByPoint(const Point& p) const
{
    auto it = std::find_if(_ships.begin(), _ships.end(), [&p](Ship& ship){ 
        auto& points = ship.getPoints();
        return std::find(points.begin(), points.end(), p) != points.end();
    });
    return it == _ships.end() ? nullptr : &*it;
}
```

Comment: `Result = &ship;` - ругается,"значение типа const Ship* нельзя присвоить Ship*. 
Result = const_cast<Ship*>(&ship);

Comment: Если Вы хотите вернуть указатель на объект, чтобы потом его *изменить* - тогда метод поиска не должен быть обозначен как const. Иначе возвращайте const Ship* везде, но тогда и метод *setDeckByPoint* должен быть const

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае, никакой move семантики не нужно. Возвращаем указатель

```
bool FindShipByPoint(const Point& p, Ship* &Result) const
{
    for (const Ship &ship: _ships)
    {
        for (const Point &_p : ship.getPoints())

            if (p == _p)
            {                  
               Result = const_cast<Ship*>(&ship); // плохо?
               return true;
            }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Плохо. `const_cast` предназначен для других ситуаций